# invoking javascript returned function as regular defined method?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to learn javascript and I've found this following code:
I don't understand how those returned functions can be called as there defined explicitly on the object (I.e mycat.makeOlder()).
can someone explain?
btw I know oop java/c#.

```
function CatMaker(name) {
var age = 10;

//construct an object on the fly with three methods.
//All methods have access to age, but age cannot be
//directly accessed outside of this function.
return { 
    "sayHello": function () { //first method
        alert("Miaow");
    },
    "getAge": function (inCatYears) { //second method
        if (inCatYears) {
            return age * 7;
        }
        else {
            return age;
        }
    },
    "makeOlder": function () { //third method
        age++;
    }
};
```

}

```
     var mycat = CatMaker('Snuffles');
     alert(mycat.getAge(true)); //returns 70
     alert(mycat.makeOlder());
     alert(mycat.getAge(true)); //returns 77
```

Comment: That are not **functions**, that are **methods** of plain object which is returned by `CatMaker`, so you have access to these methods through `mycat` variable

Comment: Can you not call the methods like in the example? The CatMaker function returns an object, specified by the `{ }` brackets. That object has some methods defined, and those can be accessed using dot notation. So `mycat.makeOlder` references a function that can be called for example.

Comment: In javascript, you don't define methods (functions in properties) in classes, you put them in objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have created some functions belonging to the `Class CatMaker`.

You can run your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2tcjxepu/

If you just declare functions outside of the `CatMaker` scope you made regular `"static" functions` you can call trough the entire file as always.

If you didn't create the class but still want to call it you can consider a [singleton](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern)